# IOS - nsstring text convert in English phonetic transcription Text

Tags: ios, text, translate, phonetics

I would like to translate an English word to its phonetic transcription work.  Only text convert.  Like I have work **hello how are you** so this will be converted to **/ˈheˈləʊ haʊ ə jʊ/**. Any one know the API?  Any demo link please share with me. .

Answer (score -1):

Try the WikSpeak in sourceforge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/wikspeak/

WikSpeak is a tool that allows non-native English speakers to analyze the correlation between the pronunciation and spelling of English words. This program is a simple and fast graphic interface which can retrieve the phonetic transcription ( IPA ) and the pronunciation of any English word, while avoiding the annoying process of browsing dictionaries. The most outstanding features of WikSpeak are the savings in time to determine the pronunciation of English words and the ease in understanding phonetic transcription.
WikSpeak is a highly recommended tool for anyone from the beginner to the advanced non-native English speaker.